# wamp like environment for node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm looking to do some learning with node.js, but I'm having difficulty getting the basic environment setup correctly. I was hoping someone could point me toward a prebuilt stack like WAMP or at least some thorough instructions on building one.

I'll looking for node.js with mysql (or similar sql implementation), I don't need anything more than a learning environment, so things like security are not currently a concern. If I get php on the same stack, that's an optional bonus.

I have some experience with servers and the command line, but I'm not an expert.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this software its for windows only http://winginx.com/en/ it has nodejs and mongoDB

Answer (score 0):

For learning Node Js ,

As i see you in windows , i would recommend you to go through these steps

Step 1 ,
Download and Install the latest version of [Sublime Text 3](http://www.sublimetext.com/3).Please use the latest version only@Build 3065

Step 2 , 
Set Sublime text to use it in  [command line](http://scotch.io/tutorials/text-editors/open-sublime-text-from-the-command-line-using-subl-exe-windows) @"subl / subl.exe"

Step 3 ,
[Download Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/install.html) So that you can use Linux Commands on windows

Step 4 , 
Watch this video(https://www.youtube.com/embed/hh-V6el8Oxk)as it will help you to install cygwin , download important packages , and set it to the path of environment variables

Step 5 , 
[Download Node.js](http://nodejs.org/download/)

Step 6 ,
Watch an [Introduction](https://www.youtube.com/embed/jo_B4LTHi3I) by Ryan Dahl , the nodejs creator

Step 7 , 
Watch this Video Tutorial Playlist for [learning Node](https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLzJZ3ahfm9Q9kwUuoJadCgNlgnCR4xYwp) . Please note that in this tutorial he is helping on how to install node.js on linux , windows and mac each respectively but gonna use mac for teaching and 
will use emacs editor (emacs) or Vim editor (vim) but as you on windows 
you would be using Sublime Text 3 (subl) on the command line !

I Hope thats help , lil tough to see from outside but actually not @personal experience

Else , If you like my guidance , please vote me , thanks !

Comment: I've been using Cygwin for years but recently discovered MobaXterm - that may be a useful alternative for some (considerably less hassle to setup though the integration with Windows isn't as tight)

Comment: thanks buddy so can i use it side by side with cygwin ? or not ? will it get any trouble/problem for me or its ok ? @psema4

Answer (score 0):

The solutions like WAMP, XAMPP, ... have been created to simplify the configuration activity of a full stack Web Server (install and Configure Apache from Scratch is not an easy task).
Setting up a nodejs web server is so easy that nobody felt the need of creating full-stack solutions.
So my advice is to start from the easiest tutorial you find online: I found very useful this one http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2013/node-express-mongo/ which illustrates the steps to build a web server with nodejs+Express+mongodb.
And yes, I suggest you to work with mongodb unless you need a db for a strong relational model.